# How do I remove as set of characters from a string in TypeScript

Tags: html, typescript

Consider, I have the following lines of code in a single variable of type string:

```
let a='<img alt="image1" height="200" src="image1.jpg" width="800">
       <img alt="image2" src="image2.jpg" height="501" width="1233">
       <img alt="image3" width="823" height="223" src="image3.jpg">'
```

Note that the properties of the various images can be in different order.
I need to remove all the height and width elements from the string.

Comment: Your string is invalid, as it contains double quotes to delimit it and also within the string itself. Are you using some different code than this?

Comment: @Adriano my code is way to large. The idea is the same. I have a string which I need to display as InnerHTML. The width and height elements are a giving me a hard time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
let a=`<img alt="image1" height="200" src="image1.jpg" width="800">
       <img alt="image2" src="image2.jpg" height="501" width="1233">
       <img alt="image3" width="823" height="223" src="image3.jpg">`;



let clean = a.replace(/((height|width)="\d*")/g, "");
```

Regex replace will remove your width and height. I've used back ticks on the string because it was multi line. The replace function takes in a regex, with the global flag to remove all occurrences and replaces them with nothing.